# Is there is any way to check map function output in mongo map reduce query?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I wana check map function output in mapReduce query in Mongo.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you make the reduce function build an array of all the mapped values then that should give you what you want. This can be achieved like this (untested, as my only server is very busy):

```
var map = function(){
    // whatever you want to group your values

    emit (key, value);
}


var reduce = function(mapKey, mapVal){
    redVal = {
        "mapped_vals" : []
    };

    for(var idx=0; idx< mapVal.length; idx++){
        redVal.mapped_vals.push(mapVal);
    };

    return redVal;
}


db.col.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "mrOut"})
```

Comment: @Gaurav If this answer helped you and produced the output you needed, please accept the answer. Alternatively, if it didn't work, please highlight what was wrong and we can look to find a better answer or improve this one.

Comment: Ya it work but it's going out of memory so i used query option to reduce dataset